# Реклама в/на транспорте

Tags: выбор-слов, предлоги

Сегодня утром в маршрутном такси увидел заголовок:

> реклама **в** транспорте

Правильно ли я понимаю, что *в транспорте* означает внутри транспортного средства (грубо говоря для пассажиров), а *на транспорте* означает снаружи ТС (условно для других участников дорожного движения)?

Comment: Согласен с Вашим пониманием *в транспорте*, но *на транспорте* понимаю как *в транспортной отрасли*. Потому что ещё до торжествующей рекламной поступи словосочетание с этим предлогом имело такое значение. Не уверен, правда, в широкой солидарности масс с этим моим мнением.

Comment: Размышляя над этим вопросом, чувствую себя нерусским... Почему-то не сталкивался с этими выражениями никогда (ни с "на", ни с "в"). А раз не слышал, чутьё ничего не подсказывает, остаётся читать других и верить тому, что они пишут. :)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказала, что "в транспорте" — разговорное выражение (тогда уж в общественном транспорте или в транспортном средстве), а нормативное одно - на транспорте.

В словарях находим:

*Реклама на транспорте* — разновидность рекламы, достигающая миллионов людей, которые пользуются общественным транспортом. Бывает трёх видов:

1. внутрисалонные рекламные планшеты, постеры в общественном транспорте;
2. наружные рекламные планшеты, размещаемые на задней, передней частях, а также на боковых сторонах транспортных средств;
3. станционные плакаты, размещаемые на станциях, остановках общественного транспорта и вокруг них.

[Источник](http://vslovare.ru/slovo/jekonomicheskiij-slovar/reklama-na-transporte/303325)

Comment: Про это как раз и был вопрос по сути)

Answer (score 0):

*На транспорте* означает то, что реклама находится на левой или правой стороне (правда, бывают и другие позиции) автобуса или автомобиля. *В транспорте*, безусловно, означает такую рекламу, которая находится внутри транспортного средства. Разве может быть иная трактовка?

Comment: Да, может. Моё сомнение в том, что *реклама на транспорте* может означать всю рекламу (включая и *в транспорте*). Вы же не говорите *я поеду **в** метро*, а вместо этого говорите *я поеду **на** метро*.